# Visual studio 2008 class template missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

My class template is missing from the "add new item" dialog.

this file exists and has the template files inside

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

but the cache folder is empty:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

I have tried

manually copying files to cache folder

deleting cache folder to let VS recreate it

devenv /installvstemplates

devenv /resetsettings

devenv.exe /resetuserdata

but nothing shows up and the Class.zip folder in ItemTemplatesCache remains empty

Answer (score 1):

Recap:

You mentioned running `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` and that the `Class.zip` file is in the `ItemTemplates` folder and the description for that from **MSDN** is:

> Registers project or item templates
>   that are located in
>   \Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates
>   or
>   \Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates
>   so they can be accessed through the
>   New Project and Add New Item dialog
>   boxes.

Yet the class item template is still not registering when you create a new class from `Add New Item`

---

Maybe try deleting (backup first) your Visual Studio 2008 App Settings completely located `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0` or login as a different user to Windows and see if the same issue exists.

---

And of course as a last resort re-install VS 2008

Comment: @PeterGoras could you qualify your comment, my answer made three points **1)** you've run the most relevent command line fix `/installvstemplates` **2)** try removing the relevent `appdata` and **3)** all else fails you can run a `Repair` install.   Barring these options I think you're left with continuing to hack at the problem or contact MS directly for resolution

Comment: So what do you do if you are using VST 2008 Pro and the devenv.exe isn't on the DVD?  I am missing the Installer class template, kind of important when I want to deploy app to Phone.

Answer (score 0):

refresh cache in the ItemTemplatesCache folder